# How to execute another java program via shell command from java program

Tags: java, shell

I am supposed to make an IDE for my project. Here I have to execute a java program(suppose Hello world ) via a Shell command from a specific java program. I know how to execute a shell command via java program (using Runtime.getRuntime()),but how do I invoke run a java program using this shell command.

Comment: First, use `ProcessBuilder`, second, how would you normally do it?  Something like `java ...` perhaps?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, the command I use, without anything fancy like garbage collector arguments is: 1. Navigate to the right folder with `cd`, then 2. call `java -jar filename.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Start with `ProcessBuilder`, it will allow you to separate each command argument as a separate parameter, removing the need to "quote" arguments that have spaces (like paths), it will allow you to specify the starting location of the command (working directory) and the redirection support makes it easier to extract information from the output of the command (although you might like to keep it separate)...

```
 List<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>(5); // You can use arrays as well
 cmds.add("java");
 cmds.add("-jar");
 cmds.add("filename.jar");
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.directory(new File("...")); // Working directory...
 Process p = pb.start();
 // Normal processing of the Process...
```

You can even specify the environment variables passed to the process...

Take a look at the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more details

Comment: I dont have a jar file, but a .java file.

Comment: @user3518031 And why should that make a difference?  All that does is change the command line...

Answer (score 0):

This will work. 
Setup the commands and then create runtime and execute command there.

```
String command[] = new String[4];
command[0] = "cmd";
command[1] = "/k start cmd /k";
command[2] = "java";
command[3] = path;

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  //This will allow you to supply with input
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));  //This will provide you access to the errors.
pw = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());      
pw.println("next commands");
```

The `PrintWriter` object will allow you to execute more commands.